# Adding relationships between an array of array of objects in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have three arrays of objects as shown below:

```
const org = [
  { 
     id: "orgId1",
     name: "first organization"
  },
  { 
     id: "orgId2",
     name: "second organization"
  }
]

const location = [
  { 
     id: "loc1",
     name: "Texas"
  },
  { 
     id: "loc2",
     name: "New York"
  }
]

const contacts = [
  { 
     id: "contact1",
     name: "James"
  },
  { 
     id: "contact2",
     name: "John"
  }
]
```

What is the optimal way to add relationships between them? Note that the arrays are of the same length.

I need a Cypher query that can loop through a range from 0 to orgs.length, and add corresponding relationships between each element at i. e.g org[i], contacts[i], location[i]

I tried the following, but it gives me an explosive combination where the first org maps to all the entries in location array and contact array, when I want is a one-to-one mapping.

```
UNWIND $orgs as orgs
UNWIND $locations as locs
UNWIND $contacts as contacts

    FOREACH (i IN range(0, size(orgs) - 1) 
        | MERGE (:Organization { id: orgs[i].id })-[r:LOCATED_AT]->(:Location {id: locs[i].id})
       | MERGE (:Organization { id: orgs[i].id })-[r:CONTACT_AT]->(:Contact {id: contacts[i].id})
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to UNWIND all arrays

```
WITH $orgs AS orgs,
     $locs AS locs,
     $contacts AS contacts

UNWIND $orgs as orgs


FOREACH (i IN range(0, size(orgs) - 1) |
    MERGE (org:Organization { id: orgs[i].id })
    MERGE (loc:Location {id: locs[i].id})
    MERGE (contact:Contact {id: contacts[i].id})
    MERGE (org)-[:LOCATED_AT]->(loc)
    MERGE (org)-[:CONTACT_AT]->(contact)
)
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

A solution was posted in the official Neo4j site. I'm sharing here as well.

```
UNWIND range(0, size($orgs) - 1) as i
with i
MERGE (o:Organization { id: $orgs[i].id })-[r:LOCATED_AT]->(l:Location {id: $locs[i].id}) 
with o, i
MERGE (o)-[r2:CONTACT_AT]->(l2:Contact {id: $contacts[i].id})
```

Link to original [answer](https://community.neo4j.com/t/adding-relationships-between-an-array-of-array-of-objects/44343/3)